# How do I make content slide while erasing/adding it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am learning jquery/ajax and I got this problem... I want to make content slowly slide up for 1 second while erasing that content... I know that I can erase container content with a command like `$(".page1" ).empty();` but I want to erase it slowly... In the mean time, I want server to work on something...

Here is what I have:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="mainScript.js"></script>
    <title>ZZZZ</title>
</head>

<body class="main">

<div class="pageMain1" id="page">

    <div class="page1">
        <p>Text...text.......Text...text.......vText...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......
        Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......</p>
        <p>random image</p>
        <img src="1.jpg"/>
        <p>Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......
        Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......</p>
        <img src="2.jpg"/>
        <p>Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......</p>
    </div>

    <div class="page2">
        <button onclick="ButtonClick(0)">Button1</button>
        <button onclick="ButtonClick(1)">Button2</button>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

mainScript.js:

```
var SiteName="/test";

function ButtonClick(id){
    $(".page1" ).empty();
    if(id==0){
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:SiteName+"/A1.php",
                dataType:"json",
                success:success,
                error:error
            });
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:SiteName+"/A2.php",
                dataType:"json",
                success:success,
                error:error
            });
    }
}

function error(){
    alert("Something went wrong.");
}

function success(arr){
    var text=arr['text'];
    $(".page1").append(text);
}
```

A1.php:

```
<?php

echo json_encode(array("text"=>"
    <div class=\"page1\">
        <p>Text...text.......Text...text.......vText...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......
        Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......</p>
        <p>random image</p>
        <img src=\"1.jpg\"/>
        <p>Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......
        Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......</p>
        <img src=\"2.jpg\"/>
        <p>Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......</p>
    </div>
"));

?>
```

A2.php:

```
<?php

echo json_encode(array("text"=>"
    <div class=\"page1\">
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....
        123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
        <p>random image</p>
        <img src=\"3.jpg\"/>
        <p>Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......
        Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......Text...text.......</p>
        <img src=\"4.jpg\"/>
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
        <img src=\"5.jpg\"/>
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
        <p>123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....123124124123123....</p>
    </div>
"));

?>
```

styles.css:

```
.pageMain1{
    width:50%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

So here is how I imagine what I want... You press Button1 or Button2 and it will call ButtonClick() function... Which will send ajax request to the server and then will slowly start moving 2 buttons up, erasing the content of the div page1.
When the content of the div has been fully erased and client got data from the server it should start slowly writing new content, while moving buttons down.
I hope its easy to follow...
How do I make it slide like that?

Comment: I would try to make a container div that has `overflow:hidden`. Then when you want something to slowly erase just do [`.slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) on the content, so in reality it's just slowly moving the div outside of the container. But because the container's overflow is hidden it will *appear* as if it's slowly erasing. Then just slide the second page in using `slideDown` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone I came up with a solution...
I made 2 more global variables and made callbacks like this:

```
var lock1=0;
var text="";
function ButtonClick(id){
...
   $(".page1").slideUp(function(){
        if(lock1==1){
            lock1=0;
            $(".page1").empty();
            $(".page1").append(text);
            $(".page1").slideDown();
        }
        else{
            lock1=2;
        }
    });
...
}

function success(arr){
    text=arr['text'];
    if(lock1==2){
        lock1=0;
        $(".page1").empty();
        $(".page1").append(text);
        $(".page1").slideDown();
    }
    else{
        lock1=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can not understand your code but for doing this things you can use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` `jquery` functions or directly change the css opacity of your element with `javascript` or `jquery` animate() function.

Comment: Ummm, you did not undestand me... I dont want it to fade, I want the content in div page2 slowly slide up or down while erasing the content of div page1.
You know... Like a sliding drop down menu, but i want it with the whole div that contains images.

Comment: i know what you want but for this things you should write your own code or use a ready to use slider, i have no time for writing that code for you but i can help you what you should do. for what you want you should select page1 move it and change its opacity to .8 then .6 until 0 , with animate() function and in animate() call back function select another page and change that one opacity from 0 to 1 . do you need example code ?

Comment: animate() just moves the object... I want a similar effect to slideUp() and slideDown() functions... But if I make something like:
    $(".page1").slideUp();
    $(".page1").empty();
    $(".page1").append(text);
    $(".page1").slideDown();

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach to this. If you do not understand the question, add a comment asking for clarification

Comment: look at this code :$(".page1").animate({'top': '-1000px','opacity':'0'},1000,function(){
 $(".page2").animate({'top':'0','opacity':'1'},1000);

});
and in your css : .page1{top:0; opacity:1;} .page2{top:-1000px; opacity:0}
and for using this code you should stay untile page 2 loads completely then run this code

Comment: But I am also waiting for ajax callback from the server. How do I combine 2 of them together? I want to execute $(".page1").empty(); $(".page1").append(text); $(".page1").slideDown(); when 2 conditions are true in the same time: 1. We got callback from server. 2. slideUp() has been finished.

Comment: i think instead of writing page1 this way it is better to inserting its content into another element with class="page1_content" then use my above code on that. and after effect completes use empty() function , then insert your new data into it then slide down that.

Comment: and only work on page1 because when you move content of page1 to up, page2  comes up also.

Answer (score 0):

Use callbacks on the slideX functions to append to and empty the `div`.

Example:

```
$(".page1").slideUp(400, function()
{
    $(".page1").empty();
    $(".page1").append(text);
    $(".page1").slideDown();
});
```

Comment: But I am also waiting for ajax callback from the server. How do I combine 2 of them together? I want to execute $(".page1").empty(); $(".page1").append(text); $(".page1").slideDown(); when 2 conditions are true in the same time: 1. We got callback from server. 2. slideUp() has been finished.

Comment: Use a callback within a callback?

Comment: I dont want to run slideUp() then run ajax or ajax then slideUp(), I want them to run in the same time and when both end, I want to put new content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sliding effects. Use jQuery:

```js
$('selector').slideUp(); 
$('selector').slideDown();
```

If you want fading in/ out effects:

```js
$('selector').fadeIn();
$('selector').fadeOut();
```